# What is this (probably) weed with nice fern-like foliage?

Tags: identification, weeds

What is this (probably) weed with nice fern-like foliage?

[image]

[image]

A detail from the top right of the second photo, where the stem of a plant in the background that appears to be the same species is visible:

[image]

More photos (update on request):

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

If crushed, the leaves exude scent of medium strength that resembles cut grass scent. It wasn't an unusual scent. It is not poisonous to inhale the fragrance (I am alive and feeling well so far).

The zone is 8a, photos taken in mid-March. The winter was mild.

---

I found two similar plants using internet searches, which I hope my plant is NOT:

- [Conium maculatum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conium_maculatum)
- [Ambrosia artemisiifolia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambrosia_artemisiifolia)

Comment: I think it is not a weed nor a fern. But if you have doubt about ferns, you should take a photo of the bottom part of the leaves, and the stem (or usually lack of it)

Comment: Ok, it looks a little bit like fern, especially from the distance. :) I'll provide any requested or suggested photo, but it may be with several days delay. Thanks for the hint @Giacomo . I do not mind having this plant, actually it gives me nice "jungle" aestetics feeling. But what if it is invasive, or drain energy and water from the soil much better than other surrounding plants, that I planted ladt year? This plant wasn't there last year. If it is a native wildflower, I would definitely like to keep it. But I don't know that.

Comment: Vivid, does it have an odor if you crush a leaf?

Comment: I don't know. I can't check right now, perhaps in next couple of days. But what if it poisonous? If I don't appear on this site for a week, it is poisonous if crushed and smelled. @Jurp

Comment: Looks a little different than the wild hemlock we have round here. Does it grow low to the ground through winter, like hemlock? From pix, you may not even have winter. Those long thick stems look decidedly not-fernlike.

Comment: I was thinking maybe Sweet Cicely (Myrrhis odorata). If it is, it would smell like anise and have white, umbelliferous-ish flowers later in spring. This is a European herb/wildflower and a US weed.

Comment: This is one of the cases where lots of detail helps, the genus Apiaceae is so darn huge ;-). So from close-ups of stems to smell, from place (dry, wet, sunny, shade...) to soil type.... If you worry about poison, wear gloves and don’t eat it!

Comment: Wild geranium?  That would have a distinctive smell.  Use latex gloves to crush...

Comment: I wonder if this is a Bleeding Heart a Dicentra of some kind?  https://www.michiganbulb.com/product/fernleaf-bleeding-heart-mix?p=0819680&gclid=CjwKCAjws6jVBRBZEiwAkIfZ2kVkmSNHSqn84i46ZRMyRAy0jXHi_t-JT2iEzFuakGcGQ6R9M0sy8xoCwHwQAvD_BwE

Comment: @Giacomo I uploded new photos.

Comment: @Jurp I uploded new photos and added fragrance test results.

Comment: @Wayfaring I uploded new photos.

Comment: @Stephie I uploded new photos.

Comment: @stormy I uploded new photos.

Comment: This appears to be the first year in the biennial life of Poison Hemlock. http://www.illinoiswildflowers.info/weeds/plants/poison_hemlock.htm

Comment: But b.nota's cow parsley info is fabulous.

Comment: Vivid, this really looks like poison hemlock.  Is there a thick taproot beneath the ones you pulled out?  The second year I suspect it will look exactly like the pictures of poison hemlock.  They look so grey yet some of your pictures look like a glossy green.  Those purple spots are very telling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On first thought it seems like [cow parsley](http://www.jackravenbushcraft.co.uk/hemlock-cow-parsley/) (*Anthriscus sylvestris*), but after reading stormy's comment about Poison Hemlock it is more likely to be that. Be careful not to eat it before you are absolutely sure about if it is poisonous or not.

Comment: This is very helpful. I hope the stem color will tell the species. But these are very young plants, perhaps stem coloration is not yet developed.

Comment: I updated the question with new photos. Some purple spots on stems worry me.

Comment: It might be Poison Hemlock instead, check the link in stormy's comments about Poison Hemlock. Don't eat it, it seems Socrates was killed by it!!

Comment: This is a group of similar plants, quite hard to distinguish. the foliage looks more densly packed and slightly lighter than I am used to seeing on Conium maculare, but this might just be a very healthy specimen.